# send DTMF tones in ongoing call

Tags: callstack, dtmf

Hello I am new in android and I wanted to know that it is possible in android to send DTMF tones in ongoing call? 
I want to do following in android. Is it possible ?

1) call +xx xxxxxxx

2) wait to the first tone to end

3) insert pass: xxxx

4) wait for the short high tone to end

5) press 1 till you hear specific sound.

Here tones are DTMF tones and I tried to do it with call intent but how can i enter pass in ongoing call using code?

Can anybody guide me ?

Thanks in advance !

Please help me to find out this. I want to know how it works. I search more and more in internet but i don't get perfect idea about this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `VOIP` only it is possible,Android applications have no access to the in-call audio stream. You can fake a it a bit in speakerphone mode.

Answer (score 2):

try disabling the `microphone` (maybe via `AudioManager.setMicrophoneMute`) while the tone is played.